# get quotation marks inside tag with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hy there. I'm trying to get all quotation marks inside a specific start- end-string.
Let's say I have this string:

```
`Hello "world". [start]this is a "mark"[end]. It should work with [start]"several" "marks"[end]`
```

Now I want every " inside the [start] .. [end] to be replaced by `&quot;`:

```
$string = 'Hello "world". [start]this is a "mark"[end]. It should work with [start]"several" "marks"[end]';
$regex = '/(?<=\[start])(.*?)(?=\[end])/';
$replace = '&quot;';

$string = preg_replace($regex,$replace,$string);
```

This matches the text between [start] and [end]. But I want to match the " inside it:

```
//expected: Hello "world". [start]this is a &quot;mark&quot;[end]. It should work with [start]&quot;several&quot; &quot;marks&quot;[end]
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Use a `preg_replace_callback` and work on the quotes separately.

Comment: Please check my comment below my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach with a `preg_replace_callback` allows to use a simpler regex (considering your string always has paired non-nested `[start]...[end]` pairs):

```
$string = 'Hello "world". [start]this is a "mark"[end]. It should work with [start]"several" "marks"[end]';
$regex = '/\[start].*?\[end]/s';
$string = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($m) {
    return str_replace('"', '&quot;', $m[0]);
},$string);
echo $string;
// => Hello "world". [start]this is a &quot;mark&quot;[end]. It should work with [start]&quot;several&quot; &quot;marks&quot;[end]
```

See the [PHP IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/pkCG4N)

The `'/\[start].*?\[end]/s'` regex matches `[start]`, then any 0+ chars (incl. a newline since the `/s` DOTALL modifier is used, and then `[end]` follows.

If you need to ensure the shortest window between the first `[start]` and `[end]`, you will need to use a regex with a tempered greedy token as in Revo's answer:  `'/\[start](?:(?!\[(?:start|end)]).)*\[end]/s'` (see [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Ox3Weu) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yD9qH6/1)).

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?s)"(?=((?!\[start\]).)*\[end\])
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/zR7eR0/3)

Explanation:

```
 (?s)                       DOT_ALL modifier
 "                          Literal "
 (?=                        Begin lookahead
      (                         # (1 start)
           (?! \[start\] )          Current position should not be followed by [start]
           .                        If yes then match
      )*                        # (1 end)
      \[end\]                   Until reaching [end]
 )                          End lookahead
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/OjFFE)